# Is this docker service exposed to the internet?

Tags: postgresql, docker, networking, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a set of docker services (orchestrated by `docker-compose`) running on a DigitalOcean host machine.

Excerpt from my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
web:
  build: backend_api_using_db
  ports: 
    - "80:80"
  depends_on:
    - db

db:
  image: postgres
```

([full version here](https://github.com/Biarity/DockerStarter/blob/master/docker-compose.yml))

Note that the `postgres` image description on Docker Hub mentions that it's Dockerfile has an `EXPOSE 5432` (postgresql's default port), which is why my `web` service can successfully connect to it.

**Is it possible to directly connect to my postgres database from outside the host machine (the internet)? What about from the inside (ssh->localhost)?**

I am asking this because I want to know how bad would it be if my postgres password was publicly shared. Can an attacker use it to gain access to my database?

Comment: I have capture some literature on [container networking](https://medium.com/@tomdeore/docking-a-docker-container-part-3-networking-edd779f068cb), this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about Docker networks in conjunction with compose files here -> https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/. Followup documentation would be -> https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links

In the shown examples there you can learn how to link containers (web <-> db). Therefore you have to only expose the web frontend port and not the db port.

Modified example from the link above (not tested):

```
version: "3"
services:

  app:
    build: ./app
    networks:
      - backend
    ports: 
      - "80:80"
  db:
    image: postgres
    networks:
      - backend

networks:
  backend:
    driver: overlay
```

Comment: I figured that much in my post, what I'm asking is whether `db` is accessible from the internet and from the host machine or not.

Comment: No, if you haven't a port section in your db service (which you dont have), then no. No port of db will be exposed until you specify a ports section in your compose file for db. You should not see a port mapping in `docker service inspect db`